# Insert Element in specific position in one dimentional array in c

Tags: c

So I want this output:

```
Position you wanted to insert
2

Value You wanted to insert
34

Array after insertion:
10 5 34 46 2 100 97
```

But it can't show me the output, what do I do please help me, and fix it..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){
    int arr[100] = {10, 5, 46, 2, 100, 97};
    int n, max, i;
    n = 0;

    clrscr();
    if(i > n){
        printf("postion you wanted to insert");
        scanf("%d", &n);
    }

    printf("Value for position: \n");
    scanf("%d", &max);

    for(i=7; i>n-1; i--){
        arr[i+1] = arr[i];
        arr[n] = max;
    }

    printf("Array after insertion: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: You have undefined behavior in your code: When you declare the local variable `i` its value becomes *undefined* unless you initialize it. You need to initialize it before you use it in the `if (i > n)` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have not assigned any value to the int i, so the compiler will assign garbage value to the variable i, hence you are not getting your output.

You need to do something like this

```
void main()
{
 int n,val,i;
 int arr[100] = {10,20,30,40,50};
 printf("enter the position where you want to insert the new element \n");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 print("Enter the value you want to insert");
 scanf("%d",&val);

 for(i=5,i>=n,i--)
  {
   arr[i+1]=arr[i];
   }
arr[n]=max;
/*then print your array*/
getch();
}
```

Comment: so how can i assign that and get my sorted array

Comment: remove the if(i>n) condition, just take the position where the user wants to insert the new value, vacate that position and enter the new value on that position.

Comment: That matters only for the first `if` statement. When used in the loops it's initialized.

Comment: You were also doing one mistake of assigning arr[n]=max within the loop module, this way everytime the loop runs the position n will have the value max, place this outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop to move the items after the index you want to insert (that is, the first loop) is wrong. You start the array with six entries (index `0` to `5`. But then you start looping with index `7`, meaning you will move `arr[7]` to `arr[8]`.

But that's just the *start* of the problems with that loop. You *then* set `arr[n]` to the value you want to insert, in each loop. So that when you want to move the original value of `arr[n]` that value have already been overwritten many times.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this:

```
 if(i > n) {
     printf("postion you wanted to insert");
     scanf("%d", &n);
 }
```

But `i` is uninitialized.

Try this:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>

 int main(){
     int arr[100] = {10, 5, 46, 2, 100, 97};
     int n, max, i = 7;
     n = 0;

     clrscr();
     if(i > n){
     printf("postion you wanted to insert");
     scanf("%d", &n);
     }

     printf("Value for position: \n");
     scanf("%d", &max);

     for(i=7; i>n-1; i--){
     arr[i+1] = arr[i];
     arr[n] = max;
     }

     printf("Array after insertion: \n");
     for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
     printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
     }

     getch();
 }
```

But you don't need this condition `if(i > n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `if` statement :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    int arr[100] = {10, 5, 46, 2, 100, 97};
    int n, max, i;
    n = 0;

    clrscr();
    // no need for if statement here
    printf("postion you wanted to insert");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Value for position: \n");
    scanf("%d", &max);

    for(i=6; i>n-1; i--) {
        arr[i+1] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = max;
    }

    printf("Array after insertion: \n");
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }

    getch();
}
```

The `if` statement uses `i`, which you have not initialized.  Since you want to ask for a position from the user, you don't need the `if` statement.

You also need to fix your `for` loop (`i` starts with 6, and you need to do `arr[i] = max` instead of `arr[n] = max`).

Comment: output not getting me it gives me the copied element not shifted like position you wanted to insert: 2 value for position: 23 Array after insertion: 10 5 23 23 2 100 97 not 10 5 23 46 2 100 97 i want second output

Answer (score 0):

change

```
for(i=7; i>n-1; i--) {
    arr[i+1] = arr[i];
    arr[n] = max;
}
```

to

```
for(i=7; i>n-1; i--)
    arr[i+1] = arr[i];
arr[n] = max;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix:

```
for(i=5; i>=n-1; i--) { //Start from end of array till n-1
arr[i+1] = arr[i]; 
 }
arr[n-1] = max; // Make room for new element & insert at last
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int main ()
{
    int arr[100] = {10, 5, 46, 2, 100, 97};
    int n = 6; //Number of elements in arr
    int pos = 0;
    int value = 0;
    clrscr();

    printf("postion you wanted to insert");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    printf("Value for position: \n");
    scanf("%d", &value);

    int i;
    for (i = n ; i > pos ; --i)
        arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
    arr[pos] = value;
    ++n;

    printf("New array:\n");
    for (i = 0 ; i < 0 ; ++i)
         printf("%d ", arr[i]);

    getch ();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution. You have to be careful about the numbers of elements already existing in your array.
Note : Disable the second if statement if you want to be able to insert in all positions possibles.

Help it'll help you :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_EL 100
int main() {
int arr[MAX_EL] = {10, 5, 46, 2, 100, 97};
int n, max, i;
int nb_elements = 6 ;
n = 0;
i = 0 ;


printf("postion you wanted to insert :\n");
scanf("%d", &n);


printf("Value for position: \n");
scanf("%d", &max);

if (nb_elements >= MAX_EL) {
   fprintf(stderr,"Tab is full ! \n") ;
   return -1 ;
}

if (n>nb_elements-1)
    n = nb_elements ;

int arr_tmp[MAX_EL] ;
for (;i<n;i++) {
   arr_tmp[i] = arr[i] ;
}
arr_tmp[n] = max ;
for (i=n;i<nb_elements+1;i++)
  arr_tmp[i+1] = arr[i] ;

nb_elements++ ;

memcpy(&arr[0],&arr_tmp[0],sizeof(int)*nb_elements) ;

printf("Array after insertion: \n");
for(i = 0; i < nb_elements; i++) {
printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
}
```

It give you the ouput  :

```
10 5 34 46 2 100 97
```